# remote display freezes & poor performance (x2go, XFCE, lightdm)

Tags: server, xfce, lightdm, x2go

I have a server runnning Ubuntu Server 20.04 with XFCE4 (lightdm) and x2go. On the client side I use the x2go client for windows on windows 10. Since the client and the server are usually in the same LAN, I use the "no-pack" option.
Connecting to the server via x2go takes quite a bit (~1 minute). Once the session is opened, it takes around two more minutes until the desktop is fully drawn.
Clicking on any Icon or trying to open any program or menu always takes at least around 30 seconds. After ~10 minutes of inactivity or after pausing and resuming a session the desktop freezes entirely, making it impossible to even log out. Killing the x2go processes using a ssh-login and then log back in using the x2go client is the only way I figured out so far to unfreeze the session.

`tail -f /var/log/syslog` reads the following on login:

```
Jun 14 11:19:46 systemd[1]: Started Session 723 of user .
Jun 14 11:19:52 /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[1704]: user-50-1623662390_stDXFCE_dp32: state file for this session does not exist: /tmp/.x2go-user/C-user-50-1623662390_stDXFCE_dp32/state (this can be ignored during session startups)
Jun 14 11:19:53 /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go Agent session with ID user-50-1623662390_stDXFCE_dp32
Jun 14 11:19:57 /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="xfce4-session"
Jun 14 11:19:57 /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: dbus wrapper available as /usr/bin/dbus-run-session
Jun 14 11:19:59 systemd[2592953]: Started GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jun 14 11:19:59 gpg-agent[2593942]: gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.2.19 starting in supervised mode.
Jun 14 11:19:59 gpg-agent[2593942]: using fd 3 for extra socket (/run/user/1050/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra)
Jun 14 11:19:59 gpg-agent[2593942]: using fd 4 for browser socket (/run/user/1050/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser)
Jun 14 11:19:59 gpg-agent[2593942]: using fd 5 for std socket (/run/user/1050/gnupg/S.gpg-agent)
Jun 14 11:19:59 gpg-agent[2593942]: using fd 6 for ssh socket (/run/user/1050/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh)
Jun 14 11:19:59 gpg-agent[2593942]: listening on: std=5 extra=3 browser=4 ssh=6
Jun 14 11:20:12 colord[4114]: failed to get seat for session 723 [pid 2594225]: No data available
Jun 14 11:20:13 NetworkManager[1237]: <info>  [1623662413.0325] agent-manager: agent[fcaf4f59c48d91aa,:1.2677/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1050]: agent registered
Jun 14 11:20:13 dbus-daemon[1235]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' unit='blueman-mechanism.service' requested by ':1.2678' (uid=1050 pid=2594226 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Jun 14 11:20:13 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Jun 14 11:20:13 blueman-mechanism[2594404]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 14 11:20:13 blueman-mechanism[2594404]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 14 11:20:13 blueman-mechani[2594404]: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jun 14 11:20:13 dbus-daemon[1235]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jun 14 11:20:13 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Jun 14 11:20:14 dbus-daemon[1235]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.2678' (uid=1050 pid=2594226 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Jun 14 11:20:14 dbus-daemon[1235]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.bluez.service': Unit dbus-org.bluez.service is masked.
Jun 14 11:20:28 /usr/bin/x2gosetkeyboard: /home/user/.x2go/C-user-50-1623662390_stDXFCE_dp32/keyboard did not appear within 30s after agent startup
Jun 14 11:20:43 systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Succeeded.
```

https://bugs.x2go.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1474 says it might be connected to the screensaver. But there is currently no screensaver installed on my system.

`tail -f /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log` reads

```
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jun 14 10:40:08 2021
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
pci id for fd 14: 102b:0532, driver (null)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open mgag200 (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
failed to load driver: mgag200
```

Answer (score 1):

Necro, but for the sake of others stumbling on it...
Have you turned off compositing? I can't tell from your logs, but your description of the symptoms sounds very familiar.

```
sed -i 's%name="use_compositing" type="bool" value="true"%name="use_compositing" type="bool" value="false"%' /home/${USER}/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml
```

Re-login, and compositing is off permanently for your user.